# Iterate with variant for loops

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, for-loop

I want to define a function that takes variant lengths `list`, and then performs `for` loops on each element (a dictionary) from the `list`.

To make it more concrete, I have provided 3 instances specifying what I am trying to achieve:

```
# preparation: create a dict to hold the data
result = dict()
for event in target.outcomes:
    result[event] = 0

#### Instance 1.
parent_list = [parent0,parent3] # element of the list is dict

for key0,value0 in parent0.items():
    for key1, value1 in parent3.items():
        for t_key, t_value in target.pmfs[(key0,key1)].items(): # current node
            result[t_key] += t_value*value0*value1

#### Instance 2.
parent_list = [parent0] # element of the list is a dict

for key0, value0 in parent0.items():
    for t_key, t_value in target.pmfs[(key0,)].items(): # current node
        result[t_key] += t_value*value0

#### Instance 3.
parent_list = [] # element of the list is a dict

for t_key, t_value in target.pmfs[()].items(): # current node
    result[t_key] += t_value
```

Desired structure:

```
def(target, parent):
    result = dict()
        for event in target.outcomes:
            result[event] = 0
    ...
    return result
```

Comment: recursive routine may be helpful in this case

Comment: Perhaps you should use recursion

Comment: How would you deal with the `target.pmfs[()]` in the very last `for` loop, since its value depends on prior `for` loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `itertools.product` instead of the nested for-loops to generate tuples of `dict`s and `functool.reduce` to multiply the values of the dicts

## Dummy data generation

```
p1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
p2 = {'c': 4, 'd': 8}
```

### Dummy mpfs

```
def pmfs(args):
    c = 10
    d = dict()
    for i, a in enumerate(args):
        d['%s_pmfs' % a] = 10 + i * 3

    if not d:
        return {'dummy': 10, 'dummy2': 15}
    return d
```

### Chainmul

The chained multiplication, from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11962031/1562285)

```
def chain_mul(iterable):
    import functools
    import operator
    return functools.reduce(operator.mul, iterable)
```

## Actual solution

If you make `result` a `defaultdict`, then you don't have to initialize it at the beginning like you do

```
def special_product(parents):
    result = defaultdict(int)

    for parent in itertools.product(*(p.items() for p in parents)):
        # print(parents)
        if parents:
            for t_key, t_value in pmfs(p[0] for p in parent).items():
                result[t_key] += t_value * chain_mul(p[1] for p in parent)
        else:    #parents was empty
            for t_key, t_value in pmfs([]).items():
                result[t_key] += t_value

    return dict(result)
```

## result

### Case 1

```
special_product([p1, p2])
```

> {'a_pmfs': 120, 'b_pmfs': 240, 'c_pmfs': 132, 'd_pmfs': 264}

### Case 2

```
special_product([p1])
```

> {'a_pmfs': 10, 'b_pmfs': 20}

### Case 3

```
special_product([p1])
```

> {'dummy': 10, 'dummy2': 15}

You will need to verify this with your `target.mpfs()`